# CSS problem when mobile device text size are set to large

Tags: css

I have a very interesting case with a website on WordPress. All responsive design is done well and it looks awesome on mobile devices. But in a very particular case, everything looks like a mess - the fonts on the website look very big, all the elements in the Slider Revolution slides also look not in place.

The issue appears when the user has set the Text size of the mobile device to Extra large. This is done in settings on the mobile phone. After that when you browse the website via the Facebook In-App Browser or Firefox, the described issue appears. In Chrome and Opera, it looks fine.

I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the header. Also tested

```
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  text-size-adjust: none;
```

But I don't see any improvement. Any ideas about what might be the problem?

Comment: text-size-adjust doesn't seem to be supported by Firefox : https://caniuse.com/text-size-adjust

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just tested the `font-size-adjust` property, seems to be working for Firefox but not on the Facebook In-App Browser.